# Перевод из str в int. Python

Tags: python

Необходимо реализовать функцию, которая переводила бы из строкового типа, в цело численный. Но БЕЗ использования сторонних, подключаемых функций, типа `int()`, `bin()` и т.п.

Думаю, что можно как-то использовать `Chаr()` и `Ord()`. Есть пример кода, но не понимаю как он работает:

```
def to_int (s):
    number = 0
    for char in s:
        number = number * 10 + ord(char) - ord('0')
    return number
```

Comment: `int` и `bin` - не "внешние", а очень даже встроенные функции. Функция `ord` возвращает числовой код символа в таблице unicode.

Comment: Не понимаю конкретно, как влияют на код:   number * 10 и - ord('0')

Answer (score 5):

- `* 10` - потому что значения соседних разрядов в числе различаются в
  10 раз. Если не умножать на 10, то в результате получится сумма цифр числа, а не само число, т.е. из `'123'` получится не `123`, а `6` (1+2+3).
- `- ord('0')` - так исторически сложилось, что в таблице
  unicode (и в таблице ASCII) символы цифр идут последовательно друг за другом от 0 до 9.
  Поэтому чтобы из кода символа цифры получить саму цифру, нужно из него вычесть код символа нуля.
  Т.е. допустим есть символ `'0'`, его код (`ord('0')`) равен N. Чему конкретно равно N в данном случае не важно. Важно, что если взять, например, цифру `'7'`, то ее код будет N+7, то есть `ord('7') - ord('0') == 7`.

Answer (score 1):

Вот упрощённая реализация аналога функции atoi из C/++:

```
def atoi(s):
  sgn = s[0] == '-'
  if s[0] in "-+": s = s[1:]
  num = 0
  for x in s:
    if x < '0' or '9' < x: break
    num = num * 10 + ord(x) - ord('0')
  return -num if sgn else num
```

Comment: Для чего она здесь?